# Append to list using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to loop pages and append/create links to the main content. How can this be done? This is what I have so far.

I'm using jquery mobile.

Thanks.

```
 $.mobile.activePage.removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e')
         .addClass('ui-body-' + $('div[data-theme]','#index').data('theme'))
         .attr('data-theme', $('div[data-theme]','#index').data('theme'));

 //pages
 $.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) {
      //HERE I WANT TO APPEND ID TO href TITLE AND VALUE TO CONTENT
 });
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>Loading...</h3>

    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#two" data-role="button">Show page "two"</a>


    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

so what I want to see is something like this....

```
<div data-role="content">

    <a href="#1" data-role="button">Show page "1"</a>
    <a href="#2" data-role="button">Show page "2"</a>
   <a href="#3" data-role="button">Show page "3"</a>


</div>
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update answer** - *based on question edit.*

```
$.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) {

 // find content div and insert links inside it
 $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content]').append('<a href=' + id + ' data-role="button">' + text + '</a>');

});
```

Old answer:

```
 $.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) {

 // append href link
 $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content] a').attr('href', siteData.id)

 // append text of <a> link
 $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content] a').html(text);

 // change the header text
 $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=header] h3').html(siteData.name);

});
```

Comment: thats cool thanks, but your code seems to be replacing not appending.

Comment: You want to append or replace? @MarkO

Comment: ok I do want to replace not append sorry. but i dont see a list of links like i should.   $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content] a').attr('href', "a"); So i'm thinking that its replacing each time

Comment: It's replacing each time because you're looping using `$.each()`. In your case, to inject data once, you dont need to use `$.each` :)

Comment: I need to use .each to list out all the data. I want to display just a list of all the pages i.e. its a navigation I'm trying to create.

Comment: @MarkO I have updated my answer. For `id` and `text` values depends on your array structure, I dont know how it looks like therefore, I cant get the exact positions inside the array.